# Better way to use for loop with increment as 01,02,03 if it is given as 01-03 and 1,2,3 if it is given as 1-3

Tags: php

I have two columns in an Excel sheet. One is country code and the other is city code.

The data is coming like this:

```
Country Code  City Code
10            01-03
```

And I have to store them in the database by making the combination of both country code and city codes as:

```
Result
1001
1002
1003
```

I.e. Country code will concatenate with the each city code in range from `01-03`.

And if the data is given like this:

```
Country Code  City Code
10            1-3
```

My result should be

```
Result
101
102
103
```

I am using a for loop to concatenate country code with the given range of city codes.

But I'm getting the result as `101,102,103` in both cases.

Can anyone suggest a better way to work with this?

My Code is

```
$mystring = $area_code_array;
                                                 $findme   = '-';
                                                 $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

                                             if($pos === false)
                                             {
                                                 $start_point = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$area_code_array);
                                                 $end_point   = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$area_code_array);
                                             }
                                             else
                                             {
                                                $explode = explode('-',$area_code_array);
                                                $start_point = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$explode[0]);
                                                $end_point   = preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$explode[1]);
                                             }
                                             for($h=$start_point;$h<=$end_point;$h++)
                                             {
```

}

The above is the code i have used **$area_code_array** is used to get the city code and it may be like 1,2,3 or 1-20, 01-20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$country  = 10;
$city     = '01-05';

$ct       = explode("-",$city);
$length   = strlen($ct[0]);
$range    = range($ct[0],$ct[1]);

$res      = array();
foreach($range as $val){
   $res[] = $country.str_pad($val, $length, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try this:

```
$number=1;
$newNumber = sprintf('%02d', $number);
```

so the value of $newNumber is : 01